# Actionmail Net::SMTPServerBusy - Sender address rejected: Domain not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer

When I try to send and e-mail with the sender adress that is not my own that is definet in my application.rb I get this error:

```
Net::SMTPServerBusy in SupportsController#create

450 4.1.8 <mail@asdasda.dk>: Sender address rejected: Domain not found
```

And if I type a valid domain I get this erro:

```
Net::SMTPFatalError in SupportsController#create

553 5.7.1 <mail@validdomain.dk>: Sender address rejected: not owned by user MY secret e-mail
```

I have followed this guide:
http://www.railsmine.net/2010/03/rails-3-action-mailer-example.html

My mailer:

```
class Notifier < ActionMailer::Base

  def support_notification(sender)
    @sender = sender
    mail(:to => "MY secret e-mail",
         :from => sender.email,
         :openssl_verify_mode  => 'none',
         :subject => "New #{sender.support_type}")
 end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like app does not authenticate itself as a 
You ned to change :from parameter to allowed email (`MY secret e-mail` in your example)